# UISplitViewController not working correct in portrait mode on iPad

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on an iOS 8 app that is using a UISplitViewController. I have a custom subclass of UISplitViewController and the app is working fine except for one small issue.

I have a button in my table view in the master that brings up a modal form sheet. The form sheet has a done button that is triggering an unwind segue that is handled in my custom subclass of UISplitViewController. This method gets called in all orientations on the iPhone and in landscape on the iPad but in portrait when the master view is a popup my method does not get called. It is like the split view is no longer in the chain so when iOS is looking for a controller that handles the unwind segue method it doesn't go all the way up to the split view. Has anyone seen this before and have any idea how to handle this situation?

Comment: May be you should handle unwind segue in some other class?

Comment: I could definitely handle the unwind segue in another class but I am wondering why it works sometimes the way I am doing it.

Comment: I think you guessed it right, that in portrait mode on iPad, split view is no longer in the chain. All we have is navigation controller and other view controllers. Again I think the only solution is to handle the segue in another class.

Comment: folks I need the workaround....Did anyone solved the problem?